# Where can I find API reference (JavaDoc) for alexa skills kit sdk2.0 for Java

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit, code-documentation

I am sure its available somewhere, I have been searching from past few days now.
All I get is git repository that has samples. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no javadoc hosted/posted by AWS Alexa team. But they have provided the offical java sdk for 2.0 API as mentioned your question. I woudl recommend to generate the javadoc using maven plugin mentioned here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html

I have just generated the javadoc using the mentioned plugin and here is the screenshot of it

[image]